# Ews login validation best way

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

is following code valid for any exchange version to validate user credentials ?

```
ExchangeService = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1, TimeZoneInfo.Utc);
                ExchangeService.Credentials = new WebCredentials(mailAddress, password);

                ExchangeService.Url =  AppGlobal.EwsAddress;   
var findFolderResults = ExchangeService.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThan(FolderSchema.TotalCount, 0), new FolderView(10));
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your using

ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1

It will work on any Exchange server that is Exchange 2010 SP1 or greater. If the server was Exchange 2007 for instance or Exchange 2010 RTM you will get error because of the Requested Server Version.

Comment: does  it work for   ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1 ?

Comment: Not with that server version specified